# Render image with a url

Tags: java, url, servlets, web-applications

I have a requirement where i have to render images on the browser. Given a url of the application should display the image in browser(Not download the image). URL would be like http://localhost:8080/image/render. Any code written already or any idea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Put this into your HTML page.

`<img src="http://site.domain/yourimage.extension"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this worked for me.
In your servlet:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        ByteArrayOutputStream bout = // write your image on the stream; you can use request.getParameter(...) and so on to have it specialize
        bout.close();
        response.setContentType("png");
        response.setContentLength(bout.size());
        response.getOutputStream().write(bout.toByteArray());
        response.getOutputStream().flush();
}
```